# Using class like moltin cart with joomla

Tags: joomla, cart

Is there any cart class you can use in joomla such as you cna use moltin cart class? i.e purely with code? moltin doesn't seem to work with joomla. The sessions seem to be overwritten by joomla so that when you var dump the cart it will always have one item.
I have tried to use the composer class moltin cart and other cart classes from packagist to implement cart functionality i.e i just want to add items using code like $cart->add($product); the problem is that these classes seem to use sessions that are overwritten by joomla with every page load thus it is impossible to add new items to the cart

Comment: This question is not properly asked. Need more details.

Comment: I have tried to use the composer class moltin cart and other cart classes from packagist to implement cart functionality i.e i just want to add items using code like $cart->add($product); the problem is that these classes seem to use sessions that are overwritten by joomla with every page load thus it is impossible to add new items to the cart

Comment: Please update your question and put some more details as you mentioned in comment.